# Search Methode Controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel

i get no result with the function to get the clubs from a search Form in a view .

Here my "Search" controller

```
    public function getClubs(Request $request){

        if($request->has('recherche')){

            $clubs = Structure::where('nom_structure' , 'LIKE', '%'. $request .'%')->where('type_structure_id' , '=' , 4)->get();



        }else{
            $clubs = Structure::where('type_structure_id' , 4)->paginate(10);
        }

        dd($clubs);

        return view('structure/clubs' , compact('clubs'));

    }
```

I tried to tape the exact name of a club but still no result , someone have an idea to get a search methode who works ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passing in the whole request change $request in the search to $request->input('recherche') or $request->recherche

public function getClubs(Request $request){

```
if($request->has('recherche')){

    $clubs = Structure::where('nom_structure' , 'LIKE', '%'. $request->recherche .'%')->where('type_structure_id' , '=' , 4)->get();

}else{
    $clubs = Structure::where('type_structure_id' , 4)->paginate(10);
}

dd($clubs);

return view('structure/clubs' , compact('clubs'));

}
```

A handy debugging function is toSql() which will show you the actual sql statement

```
 $clubs = Structure::where('nom_structure' , 'LIKE', '%'. $request->recherche .'%')->where('type_structure_id' , '=' , 4)->toSql();
```

Edit to use multiple wheres

```
  $clubs = Structure::where('nom_structure' , 'LIKE', '%'. $request->recherche .'%')
          ->orWhere('club_name' , 'LIKE' , '%'. $request->recherche .'%')
          ->whereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($request) {
              $query->where('category_name','LIKE' , '%'. $request->recherche .'%');
        })
          ->where('type_structure_id' , '=' , 4)
          ->get();
```

And My personal preference of how to do this would be

```
$search = $request->get('recherche');
    if ($search) {
      $query = Structure::Where('nom_structure', 'like', "%$search%");
    } else {
      $query = Structure::select();
    }

    $clubs = $query->where('type_structure_id', 4)->paginate(10)
      ->appends(['recherche' => $search]);
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! it's working ! if i would like to build this function with multiple search parameters . for exemple the user can search by name of the club or by the number of the club ? do i need to put an Or condition in the statement ?

Comment: Yes you just use orWhere, i have updated my answer to show this and have also added a whereHas that shows you how to search on relations if you find that useful you can find more information at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: thanks a lot !!! only problem is that my result seems to don't get this conditions ->where('type_structure_id' , '=' , 4) , in fact i tried and it display me also type_structure who are not equals to ID 4 . i want to display only clubs with type_structure_id = 4 . why the condition not work on the query ?

Comment: So ive added a 3rd answer that is a better way of doing this if you are having the where type_structure_id = 4 on every query

Answer (score 1):

In your case, `$request` is an object. You just want the input search term:

```
$clubs = Structure::where('nom_structure' , 'LIKE', '%'. $request->input('recherche') .'%')->where('type_structure_id' , '=' , 4)->get();
```